# Install certificate on Centos 7 for docker registry access

Tags: centos, ssl-certificate, docker-registry

We currently have a docker registry setup, that has security. Normally, in order to access it, from a developer's perspective, I have to do a long with the `docker login --username=someuser --password=somepassword --email user@domain.com https://docker-registry.domain.com`.

However, since I am currently trying to do an automatized deployment of a docker container in the cloud, one of the operations, which is the `docker pull` command, fails because the login was not performed (it works if I add the login in the template, but that's bad).

I was suggested to use the certificate to allow the pull from being done (.crt file). I tried installing the certificate using the steps explained here: https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/ssl-apache2-centos

But it does not seem to work, I still have to do a manual login in order to be able to perform my `docker pull` from the registry.

Is there a way I can replace the login command by the use of the certificate?

Answer (score 2):

As I see, it's wrong URL for SSL authentication between docker server and private registry server.

You can follow this:

**Running a domain registry**

While running on localhost has its uses, most people want their registry to be more widely available. To do so, the Docker engine requires you to secure it using TLS, which is conceptually very similar to configuring your web server with SSL.

Get a certificate

Assuming that you own the domain myregistrydomain.com, and that its DNS record points to the host where you are running your registry, you first need to get a certificate from a CA.

Create a certs directory:

```
 mkdir -p certs
```

Then move and/or rename your crt file to: certs/domain.crt, and your key file to: certs/domain.key.

Make sure you stopped your registry from the previous steps, then start your registry again with TLS enabled:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
  registry:2
```

You should now be able to access your registry from another docker host:

```
docker pull ubuntu
docker tag ubuntu myregistrydomain.com:5000/ubuntu
docker push myregistrydomain.com:5000/ubuntu
docker pull myregistrydomain.com:5000/ubuntu
```

Gotcha

A certificate issuer may supply you with an intermediate certificate. In this case, you must combine your certificate with the intermediate's to form a certificate bundle. You can do this using the cat command:

```
cat domain.crt intermediate-certificates.pem > certs/domain.crt
```

Comment: Yeah, I was not progressing in the right direction it seems. I don't have admin rights on the docker registry itself, so I don't know if it was started that way, but I guess it is, since I was asked to use the .crt file. However, unless I didn't understand what you said, you are using the certificate when starting the registry. When doing the `docker pull`, how can I specify the use of a certificate to access the registry? Unless I have to specify it when starting my docker daemon (on the other host) before doing the pull...

Comment: You have to specify image which you want to pull or push. For example:  once you have done build image "abc" then you want to push it into registry server. you use: "docker tag abc yourdomainregistryserver.com:5000/abc" , "docker push yourdomainregistryserver.com:5000/abc" after that, you want to download image "abc" into docker server, you use : "docker pull yourdomainregistryserver.com:5000/abc"

Comment: Excellent warning about combining the intermediate certificate with the site cert. Saved me a lot of time.